# Loadrunner Test Scenario Controller doesn't want to start and throws this : "Failed to start/stop Service Virtualization"

Tags: automated-tests, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have a Loadrunner Test Scenario, here is the snapshot for it:

[image]

after opening my Test Scenario with Loadrunner Controller, I click then the "Start Scenario" button, the Scenario must run for 2 Hours, but it stops after 1 minute, and get the following Error:

```
        Failed to stop Service Virtualization. 
        Failed to start Service Virtualization.
```

here you can see the error snapshot:[image]

to increase the size of the snapshot please: Ctrl++

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have unwittingly activated an integration with HP Service Virtualization (or SV for short), without having SV installed on the same machine. In order to remove it, open the SV configuration dialog and uncheck all the entries.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a lot of effort.
the problem is, when you have test scenario, which worked before, and you try to remove some script (groups) of the scenario,after that the test scenario will not work, what I've done, is I created from scratch a new scenario with the same test scripts, and voila it worked, I hope everyone will pay attention at that in the future